# Show the latest blog post of a certain cartegory in the homepage Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making a custom theme in Wordpress,
and I want that theme to show a home page displaying the latest (only one) post of a certain category previously created.
*Lets' say this category is called: "specificcategory".*

I made my home.php template-file and put that function in it:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1'); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
                    <?php the_content();?>
            <?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

I hope it would show the latest post (so it does) but not of the specific category, it's just displays the latest post of any category.

PS: I already have an **archive-specificcategory.php** created and used to display the list of this specific category posts.

So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to `query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1&cat=1' )` where 1 is the ID of the category you want.

See [this section](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#preserving-existing-query-parameters) of the official code ref.

Comment: It is not so different of yours.
`<?php query_post (array(
    'category_name' => 'specificcategory'
    'posts_per_page' => '1'
 )
);?>
`